# Unable to run shell script from Windows batch file

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I've been trying to do some scripting, but I can't seem to understand this one error I have.

`bash: /test.sh: No such file or directory`

Basically, I want to run a script, `test.sh`  using `bash` with the `-c` and `-l` options:

```
bash -l -c ~/opt/ct/src/test.sh
```

but this whole line is called from an Windows batch file (.cmd) located in the same directory as `test.sh`. I'm using 64-bit Cygwin (but I also have MinGW installed). I have ensured that the filepaths point to `bash.exe` (did a set PATH) and that it is the correct one, as is the shebang. I also did `dos2unix` on the script.

Any ideas on why? FYI the line I wrote worked perfectly fine in Cygwin.

Comment: Does `test.sh` exist in `c:\cygwin\home\%username%\opt\ct\src` in the Windows filesystem?

Comment: Yes, it does in fact exist.

Comment: Error message most likely indicates wrong location for test.sh, which is searched in root directory. Maybe try Cygwin style path (`/cygdrive/c/....`) and see if that helps, assuming bash is also from Cygwin?

Comment: Nope, bash is from cmd. Though I'm not sure what difference it would make if I'd called it directly from Cygwin.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit.  Instead of changing the question, mark your answer as accepted (click the big friendly check mark below the vote count so it turns green); that way, your question will no longer show up as unresolved.  (You may have to wait before you can accept your own answer, although I believe you should be past the timeout already.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I knew I had added the path to MinGW a long time ago in the Windows Path variable. It seems that when I did `bash`, it was actually running the one from MinGW and not Cygwin (verified using `which bash.exe`).

I removed the path to MinGW and voila, it worked.

Moral of the story: Never put two paths that point to two identically named program in a Path variable!